# How can I get running application names in background?

Tags: java, android, background-process

For example, Instagram is running on background. I want get running app names on my **background running application** in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way to do this you will need external libraries for this function. I have achived this once in my application by using **jaredrummler** android library. A simple usage is illustrated below

> Add to gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-processes:1.1.1'
}
```

> Create a wrapper Class Model

You can create a wrapper model like below if you want to store the basic informations about the running process to use it inside list view or elsewhere

```
...
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class RunningApplication {
     public String processName, pid = "" ;
     public long startTime = 0 ;
     public Drawable processIcon = null ;

     public RunningApplication(String name, long start, String pid, Drawable icon) {
        this.processName = name ;
        this.startTime = start ;
        this.pid = pid ;
        this.processIcon = icon ;
     }

     public getProcessName() {
        return processname ;
     }

     ...

}
```

> Use in you class

```
...
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import com.jaredrummler.android.processes.AndroidProcesses;
import com.jaredrummler.android.processes.models.AndroidAppProcess;
import com.jaredrummler.android.processes.models.Stat;
import com.jaredrummler.android.processes.models.Statm;

class YourClass extends Activity {
    List<RunningApplication> runningApplicationList = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
    public void getRunningApps() {
        List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses();
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        for (AndroidAppProcess pro : processes) {
           try {
                String proccessname = pro.name;
                Stat stat = pro.stat();
                int pid = stat.getPid();
                int parentProccessId = stat.ppid();
                long startTime = stat.stime();
                int policy = stat.policy();
                char state = stat.state();

                Statm statm = pro.statm();
                long totalSizeofProccess = statm.getSize();
                long residentSetSize = statm.getResidentSetSize();

                PackageInfo packageInfo = pro.getPackageInfo(basecontext, 0);

                //get the app name
                String appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                //Get the app icon
                Drawable appIcon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
                //Add it to your list of running app
                RunningApplication ra = new RunningApplication(appName,startTime,pid,appIcon);
                runningApplicationList.add(ra);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("APPNAME.CONTEXT",e.getMessage());
           }
        }
    }

}
...
```

**NOTE:** It been over a year since i use the above code but it work perfectly fine at that time and it is not tested. You can search for the **jaredrummler** library for more information and possible updates

Comment: thank you so much. i am developing start-up project. i will try this.

Comment: If it works for you. don't forget to mark it as the answer

Comment: bro i have problem wit this libary. when i try sync project i got this error message:" Error(26,0) / gradle DSL method nOt found implement()  ". can you help me.

Comment: i am sorry for the mistake the `implement` was suppose to be `implementation` in the gradle file or  `compile`, But compile is depreciated, see edited answer

Comment: i have still same error. " Error(26,0) / gradle DSL method nOt found **implementation** ()"

Comment: look like you are using old version of gradle use `compile` instead of `implemetation`

Comment: thanks for your answer, now i dont have any error. i know i am looks like too sticky but should i add any function my mainactivity. because this pages now hasnt any connections with my mainctivity.

Comment: yes you can add mainactivity. You can just place the import lines and the `getRunningApps()` in your activity then create the `RunningApplication` model class then add gradle. That all

Comment: Then anytime you call the `getRunningApps()` method all running process will be loaded into the `runningApplicationList` list. Dont forget to clear the list before calling the `getRunningApps()` method again

Comment: Thanks again. This system works now. But i want when  Instagram start and pause time. İs that posible.

Comment: You should read more on the `jaredrummler` library at [link](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses) there might be methods for that

Comment: thank you so much for your answers.i almost solved problems. i keep searching on likes this one.

Comment: you welcome, don't forget to upvote